# Nginx Server http to https

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, ssl, https

I installed NginX to my nodeJS server and already made Certbot SSL authentication.
Everything is working fine, but when i delete cookies and going to page, its load in **http**.
Is there any way to redirect into **https**?
When i write "return 301 https://maarath.com$request_uri;", its going to error: too many redirects.
Someone any idea?
My config:

```
server {

listen       80;
    server_name ujhonlapod.hu www.ujhonlapod.hu;

   location / {
    
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Change the port if needed
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   

   }
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name ujhonlapod.hu www.ujhonlapod.hu;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ujhonlapod.hu/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ujhonlapod.hu/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ujhonlapod.hu/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;

}
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the certbot plugin for nginx? It doesn't look like. You should remove this part

```sh
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name ujhonlapod.hu www.ujhonlapod.hu;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ujhonlapod.hu/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ujhonlapod.hu/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ujhonlapod.hu/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
```

and clean up your config to just listen on port 80.

```sh
server {

listen       80;
server_name ujhonlapod.hu www.ujhonlapod.hu;

   location / {
    
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Change the port if needed
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;  

   }
}
```

Reload nginx `nginx -s reload`

Run certbot `sudo certbot --nginx`

This should create the correct configuration for you.

Personally I would always!! split the http and https traffic in two server blocks like

```sh
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  .....

}
```

I would really recommend to use the plugin to manage the NGINX configuration if not a 100% aware on how to manage the configuration and certificates by your self. With certbot it is an act of 2 minutes to make it work.

Read more here: https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal

Comment: Thank you, it works, just runned again certbot! I pressed "no redirect" in process. :)