# How to connect https front with http spring boot backend on one VPS server with NGINX?

Tags: http, nginx, https, vps

Here is my site NGINX configuration file, I don't know how to make my https domain work with http backend, that works on the same VPS server.

I've read 4-5 questions about this problem - nothing helps

[Nginx Server http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071553/nginx-server-http-to-https-not) not working.
When i remove certbot config and add his one, my frontend stops working

[Nginx with Frontend and Backend Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778563/nginx-with-frontend-and-backend-server) - suggestion from this question isn't working too

My frontEnd can't take data from backEnd.
BackEnd works on http://localhost:8080/api/
This is the error that i get in browser console

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/category/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

```
server {

        root /var/www/greenway/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name greenway-vld greenway-vld.ru www.greenway-vld.ru www.greenway-vld

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /api{
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.greenway-vld.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.greenway-vld.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
server {
    if ($host = www.greenway-vld.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = greenway-vld.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = greenway-vld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = http://www.greenway-vld.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = http://greenway-vld.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = http://greenway-vld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name greenway-vld greenway-vld.ru www.greenway-vld.ru www.greenway-vld
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to configure and what exactly doesn't work?
If redirect from **http** to **https**, then something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl
  server_name www.greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.greenway-vld.ru/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.greenway-vld.ru/privkey.pem;
  ...
  ...
}
```

EDIT:
more complete config

1. redirect from **http** to **non-www https**

```
server {
    listen SERVER_IP:80;
    server_name domain.tls www.domain.tld;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

2. redirect from **www https** to **non-www https**

```
server {
    listen SERVER_IP:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.domain.tld;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

3. https main server block

```
server {
    listen SERVER_IP:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.tld;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam2048.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/includes/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/logs/domain.tld.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/logs/domain.tld.error.log error;
    root /var/www/domain.tld;
    index index.html index.php;
    location /
    .... 
    }
}
```

EDIT2:
Proxy to node.js application example

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Comment: I'am not getting your answer, isn't it the same confing that i have? Yes i have to redirect from http to https.

Comment: This config redirect all http domainds to https. What's wrong? Do you need something else?

Comment: It's not working or i am doing something wrong, please can you explain in details how can i change what i have into what you gave, Because if i write my conf in your way, nothing works, no front no back =(

Comment: what does `nginx -t` show?

Comment: if I delete everything what i have and put your config and add instead of your dots ssl -> nothing gonna work

Comment: ``` nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "server_name" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/greenway.conf:9
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Now even my config not working=) no frontend no backend

Comment: `server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {

  listen 443 ssl
  server_name www.greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld.ru greenway-vld;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.greenway-vld.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.greenway-vld.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

`
my config

Comment: you miss **;** semicolon after `listen 443 ssl`

Comment: added more complete config to answer

Comment: what should i write in location?

Comment: I have to redirect from http to https in oreder to make it work with front end that works with https and redirects into it from http, what are you trying to help is to redirect everything to https - this is not what the question is about.

Comment: further process requests in locations as you need, or send to the backend, i don't know all your configuration

Comment: backend works in localhost:8080/api/**

Comment: There is FrontEnd part that calls backend by http inside app.js.
FrontEnd part works on https://greenway-vld.ru/
BackEnd works on http://localhost:8080/api/

when i go to frontend - everything is ok apart content that comes from backend, because the can't talk with each other.
https cant take data from http localhost:8080

Comment: check nginx and backend log files